# Should I be able to see the seam on an L-shaped Quartz countertop?

Tags: kitchen-counters, countertops, quartz

I'm trying to get feedback on if this seam is expected from install of an L-shaped countertop.

I understand that a seam is needed, but I wasn't sure that it was going to be this noticeable.

Is there anything that can be done to make it less noticeable?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nothing wrong with that seam IMHO.

Comment: Generally a good counter company will try to have a seam match.  If you didn't object to the seam at the instal and you already paid for your counter, the unfortunate reality is that now you are stuck with it.

Answer (score 6):

The seam itself looks fine.  But it could have been tinted a little better. Admittedly all the tops we have ever had have been dark to black and the seams are almost unnoticeable.

I would approach the installer and let them know you are not happy with it and would they please colour match it a little better.  It will still be visible.  Because of the grain, you can not hide it.

Comment: Exactly. Can't invisible-seam stone. Solid surface epoxy material (Corian. Wilsonart, etc) can be seamed invisibly, depending on the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a perfect invisible seam you need stone with a more regular pattern, seams planned from matched adjacent slabs laid in the same direction, and a skilled installer.  It's a lot more expensive.   Alternately if the installation is small enough it can be cut as one piece from a single slab without a seam.  Also expensive.

It seems like the two pieces you have there were cut to make best use of an available slab, without aiming for a perfect seam.  The pattern (veins) is irregular and laid at 90 degrees across the seam.  So it cannot be invisible.

Given that, there isn't much to be gained by a more skilled installation.   It's pretty good, it's just a little too light.   You could ask the seam be redone in a color better matching the stone's background if you think you'll enjoy that more.    If you go that way it should be done by experienced people who work for the stone yard, not by your contractor or tile guy or handyman.  And for the reasons stated above, don't expect or demand perfection.

Answer (score 0):

Tell the company you want it fixed. That's horrific. I own a granite shop so trust me when I say that they should fix it